# Fixing starting location for NLA

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes, actions

I am very new to learning Blender so please bare with me on this one! I've read similar questions and tried the suggestions without success!

I have two actions I want to merge together using the NLA editor. When the second action starts, it jumps locations. I did not make these actions, I am just trying to put them together.

.blend file on Google drive here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X-3MGEjLqLDbv0jgOK1G5n3nY1bRRED4

Thank you for any advice you can offer!!

Answer (score 1):

You character jumps because its position to its origin has changed between the 2 actions.

It depends what you mean by merging actions in the *NLA Editor*. You can merge 2 strips to make one in the *NLA* but if you just want your character to have a coherent animation (i.e. have the same position at the beginning of the second action than the one at the end of the first action) you can do it this way:

- Open the *Graph Editor*. In the *NLA*, select the second strip. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> so that you can see all the bones curves in the *Graph Editor*.
- As the master bone of your armature is *Hips*, and as the shift between the 2 actions position is on its *Z* location, select the *Hips Z Location* track and press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to make all the other ones invisible.
- Select the curve with <kbd>A</kbd> and move it on its own Y axis, you can see that the armature moves in the 3D view. Move it where it is supposed to be.
- Correct on any other axis if needed.

Now keep in mind that it seems like you don't have any transition between the 2 animations, maybe it's better to create one. Also, instead of keeping two separate actions, you can choose to select all the animations of the second action in the *Dopesheet* and paste them at the end of the first one. You won't need 2 strips anymore as you've copied the content of the second one in the first one, and you'll have to correct the position the same way as explained.

[image]

Comment: This is so helpful! THANK YOU!!

I'm rendering another animation now, but I'll give this a try later today! Thank you again!