# Animating Faster (NLA)

Tags: animation

I've been using blender's NLA approach to join several individual animations together (ie run, jump, roll, turn). It seems slow having to reposition the rigs starting location for each new animation. For example, the character starts the second animation at the (x,y,z) location where the first animation ended. I can't image how complicated and long it would take to string together 10+ individual animations.

**My question is if there is a better/faster/automated way of joining animations together so that the character simply starts at the x,y,z position where the last animation finished?**
Is there any add-on or python script that does what NLA does, without having to join each animation together manually?

Comment: Does this help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144719/fixing-starting-location-for-nla ?

Comment: That approach is what I've been doing currently, but I'm looking for a simple "one-click" way to "auto-adjust" the next animation. I'm going to be joining 15+ animations sequentially to the same character, so this is going to be very time consuming. I thought there might be some add-on or python script out there but it looks like I might have to try developing some code to do it

Comment: I'm no expert but I think you'll have to roll your own for that one!

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/combining-bvh-files/599655 is close to what im looking for. The only problem is that the animation is not continuous