How do I change the location of an animation?
I'm very new to Blender and would appreciate it if you could guide me through this.
I'm trying to make a GMT animation file (Yakuza games) that's been taken from a cutscene (Its location is far from the center) and make the animation play at the center.
I've been searching for a couple of days for a solution and have tried multiple methods, but every time I export the animation and import it again, it starts playing from its original location.
Any help would be much appreciated.

No idea what a "GMT animation" is or how you're importing your animation, but see if the answer in this question helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144719/fixing-starting-location-for-nla. Although it's pretty old now there's also this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99821/how-can-i-shift-or-move-an-entire-animation-to-a-different-location?rq=1
